# Windows Embedded CE 6.00 cannot .run Net compact Framework 3.5 application

Tags: timezone, .net-2.0, windows-ce, exchangewebservices

First of all, i have a device with Windows Embedded CE 6.0. As we know, EWS Managed API can only be used on .NET Framework 3.5 and above.

I created a new project ->Smart Device Project ->

Target Platform: Window CE

.NET Compact Framework Version: .NET Compact Framework Version 3.5

Templates: Device Application

Then i tried to use EWS API library to write a program to send email from server to my email but there is an error.

Error   1   The type 'System.TimeZoneInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Documents and Settings\christopher.lim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SmartDeviceProject1\SmartDeviceProject1\Form1.cs 23  13  SmartDeviceProject1

This error occur when .NET Framework is not compatible which means my Window Embedded CE 6.0 cannot run application which need .NET Framework 3.5.

So is there anyway that i can upgrade my Window CE so that it can run .NET Framework 3.5 and above application??

Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Compact Framework, in *all* iterations, will work fine under CE 6.0 (1.0 isn't officially "supported" but it would run if you wanted to use it).

The issue you're seeing is a compiler problem, not a runtime problem.  The root of the problem is (cryptically) stated in the error, in the public key token. `b77a5c561934e089` is the public key for the desktop framework.

Basically the compiler is telling you "Hey, you're referencing a DLL that uses the desktop System.Core.dll assembly, so you need to add a reference to that DLL."  The problem with that is that the desktop System.Core.dll assembly will not run on a Windows CE device.

You have to use the Compact Framework System.Core.dll (which has a public key of `969db8053d3322ac`).  That means that whatever you're referencing (EWS Managed API) must be recompiled using the Compact Framework references, or you must find an alternate way to provide the feature/function you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since i have to use Compact Framework System.Core.dll, where can i find it?

Comment: It's part of of the CF 3.5 installation, so the 'Add Reference' dialog for a CF app should show it.  Specifically, though, it's at `%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL`

Comment: I don't think this will allow EWS API to run on .NET CF though.